# ASP.NET MVC - Where to implement mappers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could you please advise me where to put:

1. mappers for business objects and view model objects?
2. mappers for shared user controls (business object <-> control's view model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implement mapping logic between models and view models in the ASP.NET MVC tier which is the frontend tier referencing both the business objects tier and the view models which are part of it. I use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) for this mapping logic.

Comment: Darin, inside the controller body? And what about user controls which has no controllers? Thank you!

Comment: @Jim, absolutely not inside the controller body. That would be horrible. I implement the mapping logic in separate files. As far as user controls that have no controllers are concerned I don't use such things in my applications.

Comment: @Darin, i can imagine many ways where to put mapping logic (starting from repository etc) and how to separate one mappers types from anbother (by files, namespaces, ...). I would be thankful if you show me some examples of how you do it to avoid most popular troubles :)

Comment: @Jim, I use [mapping profiles](http://mhinze.com/2009/07/06/automapper-in-nerddinner/).